# Python: Unpack a byte string - various length of first "part"

Tags: python, struct, byte, unpack

First of all, this is my first question here, so please be patience with me ;-)

When connecting to a device, I receive a byte string, which contains a various number of "entries", which I want to unpack/split.

First part of the result gives me the number of entries in total, followed by all entries, which are separated by whitespaces. Since the description of every entry could have whitespaces as well, length of the description is also provided as hex.

For example, this is a result string with 2 entries:

```
2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3
```

Explanation of result:

```
2 = number of entries (hex)
A = length of description following next (hex)
Description (string)
Timestamp (hex)
Timestamp (hex)
Counter (hex)

18 = length of description
Description
Timestamp
Timestamp
Counter
```

I assume I should use struct to unpack such strings and be able to work with the results, but to be honest, I'm a bit lost on how to start. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
data = b'2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3'
print(repr(data))
b'2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3'
```

Comment: Show us the output of `print(repr(data))` where `data` is your byte string.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel see edit above ... is that what you mean?

Comment: @Kennie666, the idea was to get raw data you receive from device. Bytestring you provided doesn't look legit.

Comment: Hex A is the length of the text ‘unassigned’, while hex 18 is the length of ‘FtpC1: xml upload failed', so all the information is there.

Comment: The easiest would be to split by spaces, then loop over the result, keeping track of the state (including deciding if a sequence of values in the list are part of the same description)

Comment: @Stefan, it should look like `b"\x02\x0AUnassigned\x5F\xAD\xD9\xBF\x5F\xBE\xB4\x61\x1C\x34"`. At least. Current information is not enough, it's weird representation

Comment: @OlvinRoght hm ... unfortunately, this is all I got :-/  after creating socket s and connecting to the device,  `data = s.recv(1024)` is all I do, and this gives me the output above.

Comment: @Kennie666, could you add code how you got this? It looks super weird, device would never send numbers in form of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following

```py
data = b'2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3'

data += b' '  # pad end with a blank
n, data = data.split(b' ', 1)
n = int(n, 16)
for i in range(n):
    length, data = data.split(b' ', 1)
    length = int(length, 16)
    description = data[:length]
    data = data[length +
                1:]  # skip description and the blank after description
    ts1, ts2, data = data.split(b' ', 2)
    ts1, ts2 = map(lambda s: int(s, 16), (ts1, ts2))
    counter, data = data.split(b' ', 1)
    counter = int(counter, 16)
    print((i, description, ts1, ts2, counter))
```

Comment: imho, `ts1, ts2 = int(ts1, 16), int(ts2, 16)` looks much better than `map()` with lambda

Comment: Thank you @Justin - this works for me perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be to split the byte string, then loop over the “words” keeping track of the state.

Not the complete program, but it could start like this:

```py
s = b'2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3'

slist = s.split()
state = 'numEntries'
for word in slist:
    #print(word)
    if state == 'numEntries':
        numEntries = int.from_bytes(word, 'little')
        state = 'len'
    elif state == 'len':
        lenDesc = int.from_bytes(word, 'little')
        state = 'desc'
    elif state == 'desc':
        desc = word
        state = 'date'
        print(desc)
```

...and so on. I don't know if this is “Pythonic”, Python is not my “first language”

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helped you

```
from datetime import datetime

s="2 A Unassigned 5FADD9BF 5FBEB461 1C34 18 FtpC1: xml upload failed 5FB3CE6C 5FBD44BC 3"

number_of_entries=int(s.split(' ')[0],16)
print("Number of entries: ",number_of_entries)
print("=============================")
index_of_first_entry=s.find(' ')+1
s=s[index_of_first_entry:]

for i in range(number_of_entries): 
#if 1==1:
  length_of_description=int(s.split(' ')[0],16)

  #s.replace(' ','#',1).find(' ')+1
  print("length_of_description:",length_of_description)

  index=s.find(' ')+1

  description=s[index:index+length_of_description]
  print("description:",description)

  rest_of_string=s[index+length_of_description+1:]
  timestamp1=int(rest_of_string.split(' ')[0],16)
  date_1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp1)
  print("timestamp1:",f"{date_1:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")

  timestamp2=int(rest_of_string.split(' ')[1],16)
  date_2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp2)
  print("timestamp2:",f"{date_2:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")

  counter=int(rest_of_string.split(' ')[2],16)
  print("counter:",counter)
 
  index_of_next_entry=rest_of_string.replace(' ','#',2).find(' ')+1
  s=rest_of_string[index_of_next_entry:]
  print("-----------------------------")
```

**[RESULT]:**

> ```
> Number of entries:  2
> =============================
> length_of_description: 10
> description: Unassigned
> timestamp1: 2020-11-13 00:56:31
> timestamp2: 2020-11-25 19:45:37
> counter: 7220
> -----------------------------
> length_of_description: 24
> description: FtpC1: xml upload failed
> timestamp1: 2020-11-17 13:21:48
> timestamp2: 2020-11-24 17:37:00
> counter: 3
> -----------------------------
> ```